# Dual boot with 2 HDD's

Tags: dual-boot

I have an ASI 64bit computer with Ubuntu installed & want to install a second HDD that already has Windows 7 installed. How do I enable a Dual boot selection on start up

Comment: Why don't you use BIOS's boot menu?

Answer (score 1):

It might be as simple as adding the second hard disk with Windows and running

> sudo update-grub

This should add Windows to the grub boot menu, and if grub had not been showing up before, because there was only one OS, it should show up now and give you a choice of what to run.

---

So you have shown both disks are bootable, run the sudo update-grub to add the Windows boot menu choice and reboot, select OS desired.

Comment: I found F4 that allows you to gain access to both Hard Drives OS at this stage. Will this eventually give Dual Boot options @ start up.